# array of typedef'd strings?

Tags: c, string

I am writing a C program and because there is no string in C, I wrote the following code to work around:

```
typedef char * string
```

now I need a array of strings and the following statement gives me an error:

```
string * file1
```

the error message says:

```
Error   1   error C2275: 'string' : illegal use of this type as an expression   \\vmware-host\shared folders\school\misc\johncpp\porj\similarity.c  79
```

im on MSVC compiler
can I not create an array of strings which is essentially char **?

thanks

Comment: This is not a workaround, it's just a source of confusion.

Comment: I wish I could +1 more times, @Oli Charlesworth.

Comment: Have you tried renaming it to anything else?

(I agree that it can be confusing for others when you refer to a char* as a string, but let's face it, all the Microsoft APIs do the exact same thing.)

Comment: so should I use char** instead then?

Comment: @ShiggityShiggityShwa yes I have, when I rename it to stringA I get the same error but with stringA.

Comment: Perhaps emulating Microsoft should not be a priority.

Comment: Adding such a `typedef` seems mostly pointless.  You should just accept that strings are arrays of `char`.  Your `typedef` also won't work with `const char*`.  Perhaps your goal is to distinguish between a pointer-to-a-single-`char` and a pointer-to-a-NUL-terminated-sequence-of-`char`s, but in practice that sort of thing is obvious from context and from reasonable variable names.

Comment: It's his choice what he does with his code. It isn't really a "workaround", yes, but let's not grandstand about what is or isn't an acceptable thing to do with a typedef. He already did it and it's been done many times in the past. He just wants to know why his isn't working.

Comment: Problem solved guys, it was the line above that caused the problem 
int * s_counter1; 
*s_counter1 = 0;

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. But if I could make a suggestion related to all the complaints in this thread: try to give it a less confusing name than "string". The standard library contains a string type and you might confuse yourself (or someone else) later.

Comment: @ShiggityShiggityShwa: The C standard library does not contain a string type; you're probably thinking of C++.  In C, a "string" is by definition "a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character"; it's important to remember that a `char*` can *point* to a string, but it cannot *be* a string.

Comment: Yes, I know how strings work in C. As I alluded to in the Microsoft comment, C strings are used the same way in the Windows APIs, which you are of course able to access from C++. I could have been more specific in my last comment but I wrote it something like 20 minutes later. My point was that use of the word "string" will be confusing. And I just saw confusion happen in another C language question asked by the same person an hour later because he neglected to mention his typedef.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Oli suggests in his comment, you probably don't really want to do it at all.  Assuming you put some semicolons in the right spots, your code is legal C, however.  It must be something special about MSVC that's giving you an error.  Are you sure nothing else in your compilation unit is named `string`?

Edit: A quick check at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76c9k4ah%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) indicates you might just be declaring the variable someplace you're not allowed to - it has to be at the top of a block or outside of all blocks (i.e., a global variable).

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared `file1` at the top of the function? MSVC does not implement C99, so you must declare every variable to the top. See the comments [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76c9k4ah%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> The C compiler also generates this error if you attempt to define a
>   variable below the start of a function (legal in C99 but not earlier)
>   if that variable declaration used a typedef

Answer (score 0):

Are those exactly the code in the files?

```
typedef char * string
```

would need to be

```
typedef char * string;
```

And

```
string * file1
```

would need to be

```
string * file1;
```

This will make the error messages go away, but ...
It is still a **bad** idea because there isn't any allocated space for a string.